# Entity Framework core 3.1.1 Multilevel Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, table-per-hierarchy

An exception is thrown while running add-migration (EF core 3.1.1):

> CLR property 'DiscriminatorLevel2Id' cannot be added to entity type 'CustomerBase' because it is declared on the CLR type 'InternalCustomer'

The following Image shows the needed hierarchy (briefly):

[image: Class Diagram]

Mapping looks like:

```
// Discriminator (Level 1)
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerBase>()              
            .HasDiscriminator(b => b.CustomerTypeId)
            .HasValue<InternalCustomer>((int)CustomerType.Internal)
            .HasValue<ExternalCustomer>((int)CustomerType.External);

// Discriminator (Level 2)
modelBuilder.Entity<InternalCustomer>()
         .HasDiscriminator(b => b.DiscriminatorLevel2Id)
         .HasValue<VIPCustomer>((int)DiscriminatorLevel2.VIP)
         .HasValue<RegularCustomer>((int)DiscriminatorLevel2.Regular);
```

Is "Multilevel Inheritance TPH" supported on Entity Framework Core 3.1.1?

Comment: Multilevel discriminator - no. Multilevel inheritance with common discriminator - yes.

Comment: Thanks Ivan Stove, 
How is "Multilevel inheritance with common discriminator"  implemented, what are changes that need to be done in the above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but with single shared discriminator at the root abstract level containing values for all possible creatable (non abstract) direct or indirect derived entities.

Applying to your sample requires removing the `DiscriminatorLevel2` property (column), removing `Internal` from `CustomerType` enum (assuming `InternalCustomer` is abstract) and merging `Regular` and `VIP` into it, e.g. something like this:

*Model:*

```
public abstract class CustomerBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class InternalCustomer : CustomerBase
{
    public decimal Points { get; set; }
}

public class RegularCustomer : InternalCustomer
{
    public int PartnerId { get; set; }
}

public class VIPCustomer : InternalCustomer
{
    public string CardNo { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalCustomer : CustomerBase
{
}

public enum CustomerType { External, Regular, VIP }
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerBase>()
    .HasDiscriminator(b => b.CustomerTypeId)
    .HasValue<ExternalCustomer>((int)CustomerType.External)
    .HasValue<VIPCustomer>((int)CustomerType.VIP)
    .HasValue<RegularCustomer>((int)CustomerType.Regular);

modelBuilder.Entity<InternalCustomer>();
```

When you want to query `InternalCustomer` derived entities, you could use `db.Set<InternalCustomer>()` or `db.Set<CustomerBase>().OfType<InternalCustomer>()` and EF Core will apply filter similar to `t.CustomerTypeId IN (1,2)`, i.e. the `IN` clause will contain list of discriminator values for all final entities derived from `InternalCustomer`.